# zend_cache:I have 506790 cache files,is the cause of high IO on read reason?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

Recently I needed to speed up a legacy project(use zend framework 1.10.2),that project use zend_cache,I am new in zend framework.
the default.ini configure:

```
data.cache.interim.frontend.name = "Core"
data.cache.interim.frontend.options.lifetime = 311040000 ; 10 years
data.cache.interim.backend.name = "File"
data.cache.interim.backend.options.cache_dir = "/cache/dp-interim/"
data.cache.interim.backend.options.hashed_directory_level = 3
```

There have 506790 cache files in /cache/dp-interim (run command: `ls -lR | grep "^-" | wc -l` on /cache/dp-interim get the result).

run "iotop",get the result: `TOTAL DISK READ : 1034.22K/s`

run "iostat",the result:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.80    0.00    0.77   51.80    0.00   45.62

        Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
        xvdap1            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdb             48.00     0.00  245.00    0.00  2344.00     0.00     9.57     1.51    6.16   3.95  96.80
        xvdap3            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

        avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
                   2.05    0.00    1.03   45.90    0.00   51.03

        Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
        xvdap1            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdb             43.00     0.00  214.00    0.00  2056.00     0.00     9.61     1.10    5.20   4.47  95.60
        xvdap3            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

        avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
                   2.06    0.00    0.26   46.91    0.00   50.77

        Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
        xvdap1            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdb             62.00     0.00  196.00    0.00  2064.00     0.00    10.53     1.64    8.33   5.06  99.20
        xvdap3            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

        qavg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
                   2.33    0.00    2.59   45.34    0.00   49.74

        Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
        xvdap1            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdb             33.00     0.00  331.00    0.00  2912.00     0.00     8.80     0.99    3.01   2.68  88.80
        xvdap3            0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
        xvdf              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

It is the larger cache file cause the IO height?
Thanks for you help!

Comment: What do you asking here? What is code resulting in the statistic of iostat/iotop?

Comment: my english is poor,sorry.
I want to know  is that  500000+ cache files cause of I/O problem?